# Related Integer Combination

Tags: computer-science

The title and tags are a little goofy since I'm not quite sure what to call this.  This may be more of a computer science question, but I thought I'd ask here too.

I have two integers $n$ and $m$ that are arbitrarily (logically) related with integers $x$ and $y$, respectively, where all values are finite and $> 0.$

I'd like to know if there's a way to combine $n$ and $x$, and $m$ and $y$, into two numbers (integer, decimal, whatever) such that neither will overlap.  Additionally, I need to be able to perform some kind of operation to reverse the previous process to once again obtain $n$ and $x$, and $m$ and $y$.

Let me know if this isn't clear.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a question about two numbers, not four.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could employ a pairing function, e.g. [Cantor's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) or [others](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf).