# Reversibly Combining Very Large

Tags: algorithms

How can I reversibly combing two very large numbers, such as 9,828,485,546,536,174,656,640,115,183 and 43,044,700,185? I need them to be combined into a single number, and the order of the numbers must be remained intact, so being required to flip them would be unfavorable, but I could just add a 0 or 1 at the front or end to specify whether or not the numbers had been flipped if I had too.

Answer (score 1):

See this [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/create-unique-number-from-2-numbers/23526#23526) on [pairing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), e.g. the classical Cantor pairing or [another "elegant" one](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) useful for depth-first ordering.

Comment: Neither the elegant, nor the cantor pairing functions work for numbers this large.