# Produce unique number given two integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given two integers, $a$ and $b$, I need an operation to produce a third number $c$. This number does not have to be an integer. The restrictions are as follows:

1. $c$ must be unique for the inputs (but it does not have to be reversible).
2. $a$ and $b$ must be interchangeable ($a$ & $b$ = $b$ & $a$)

Initially, the first thing I thought of was simply $a+b$, however naturally that does not fit restriction 1. Then I considered a hash function of some sort, but that doesn't fit 2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean that doesn't fit 1, there is only one unique number which is the sum of a and b.

Comment: I believe that the OP wants an injective operation from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ as condition 1, and for the operation to be commutative for condition 2.

Comment: @qaphla Almost, except it should be $2$-to-$1$, since $f(a, b) = f(b, a)$.

Comment: Maybe, but the "does not have to be reversible" makes me think that he means "doesn't have to be injective."

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Something like let $p_i$ be the $i'th$ prime then let $a\circ b=p_a p_b$?

Comment: There is no way this can be injective, come to think of it, commutative means that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$ always as @T.Bongers notes, so addition still seems to fit in the only way that this so far makes sense.

Comment: True. Maybe a better description would be an injective function from the set of two-element subsets of $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @qaphla check out my last comment:  it's impossible to get such an injection because of commutativity.

Comment: It's impossible to have such an injection from ordered pairs, but an injection from two-element subsets is fine, since then the 'commutativity' condition is implied -- $f(\{a,b\}) = f(\{b,a\})$.

Comment: @qaphla that's true, but this particular question asks for a binary operation which is a function on ordered pairs.

Comment: I'd say that a commutative function on ordered pairs can be pretty clearly identified with a function on sets of size two, and the difference between the two isn't worth caring about.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/23505/125202

Comment: It may be that you don't need a mathematical solution (since you tried hashing). You could just use `hash(max(a,b) + ":" + min(a,b))`

Comment: You can see there are two classes of answers pure mathematical and practically computable - it would be nice if the question clarified which was actually asked for. [ I.e. Probably not a mapping from the whole set of integers.]

Comment: `f(a,b) = min(a,b) + i*max(a,b)`

Comment: @qaphla another thing that bothers me about this "subsets of size two" thing:  a binary operation can take $(a,a)$ whereas this set construction cannot because $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$, so the difference is very much worth caring about.

Comment: @AdamHughes: in my answer, I chose to interpret these as unordered pairs. I think that matches the intent better.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about just $2^a+2^b$? This represents the binary number with $1$s at exactly the $a$-th and $b$-th positions if $a\ne b$, and a single $1$ at the $(a+1)$-th position if $a=b$.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: reversible? Using this method we get a and b from c.

Comment: @mridul Any method we use is theoretically reversible (up to specifying which input is $a$ and which is $b$) because we have a uniqueness requirement - meaning from $f(a,b)$ we can extract the information $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: If we're talking about a computer, this becomes trickier as soon as $a$ or $b$ get bigger than $64$... not a great range.

Comment: @JackM The goal of this answer was to give a nice mathematical solution to the problem regardless of practicalities. For a good way to actually solve the problem on a computer, please see the other answers - say TonyK's answer, or JimmyK4542's answer.

Answer (score 34):

If we restrict $a,b$ to be non-negative integers, we can try  $f(a,b) = \dfrac{\max(a,b)(\max(a,b)+1)}{2}+\min(a,b)$.

This satisfies $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$ and grows quadratically with $\max(a,b)$. To help you see the pattern:

$f(0,0) = 0$,

$f(1,0) = 1$, $f(1,1) = 2$,

$f(2,0) = 3$, $f(2,1) = 4$, $f(2,2) = 5$,

$f(3,0) = 6$, $f(3,1) = 7$, $f(3,2) = 8$, $f(3,3) = 9$,

...

If you want to allow any integers $a,b$ then let $g$ be your favorite bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}_0$, then let $f(a,b) = \dfrac{\max(g(a),g(b))(\max(g(a),g(b))+1)}{2}+\min(g(a),g(b))$.

One such bijection is $g(n) = \begin{cases} -2n & n \le 0 \\ 2n-1 & n \ge 1\end{cases}$.

Comment: This is certainly the best solution so far from an implementation point of view.

Comment: Great answer - I can see this being very useful.

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted $f$ to take on negative values as well as positive values, you could define
$$f(a, b) = g^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\max(g(a),g(b))(\max(g(a),g(b))+1)}{2}+\min(g(a),g(b))\right).$$

Comment: I should look to see if there is a $g$ that maps my answer to yours.

Comment: this is brilliant, can you please describe how you found the solution / proved it?

Answer (score 10):

I think $a\circ b=(2^a+1)(2^b+1)$ works, if I understand correctly.  $a \circ b = b \circ a$ and $a$ and $b$ can be found (up to permutation) from $(2^a+1)(2^b+1)$ (assuming $a$ and $b$ are integers.)

Comment: Nice answer; especially since one can tell the original two numbers by glancing at the binary representation of the result.

Comment: -1 Mathematically elegant but this isn't practical to implement into code for large $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Who said anything about practicality for code?

Comment: a) The OP appears to be a programmer, b) he'd contemplated a hash function, c) even so, we should be able to find a mathematically elegant solution that others in the future can implement into code.

Comment: You are correct, I am a programmer. Ideally, a more elegant solution would be better as this is part of a function which may be integrated into an app, and I'm not sure how happy iPhones will be about doing this were a or b could be up to 10 figures long.

Comment: If you want it computable, just reduce it modulo a large prime that has 2 as a generator (larger than the square of the max int). If you don't need an ironclad guarantee of no collisions, use a smaller prime.

Comment: @deinst reducing the result modulo a prime won't help because the difficulties lie in evaluating $2^a+1$ for large $a$.

Comment: Finding a power of 2 modulo a prime is trivial.

Comment: @ozo If that's what the OP wants, then he ought to ask a more specific question. This answer perfectly fits the requirements as stated. It's ridiculous to downvote someone for not reading the OP's mind or making unwarranted assumptions from the question.

Comment: @ChrisHayes he considered a hash function; I don't think that reading the question in detail counts as 'mind reading'.

Answer (score 8):

Peter Woolfitt's suggestion ($2^a + 2^b$) is the simplest so far, but it becomes extremely large for quite small values of $a$ and $b$. For a more manageable function, I suggest interleaving the binary representations of $a$ and $b$. Then the result will be no larger than $\max(a,b)^2$.

To make it commutative ($f(a,b)=f(b,a)$), you will first have to swap $a$ and $b$ if $a< b$. Then it goes something like this:

```
f := 1
while a != 0 or b != 0
    // Incorporate bottom bit of a
    f := 2 * f
    if a is odd then f := f + 1
    a := a/2 // Discard bottom bit of a

    // Incorporate bottom bit of b
    f := 2 * f
    if b is odd then f := f + 1
    b := b/2 // Discard bottom bit of b
wend
```

Comment: And what happens to the uppermost bits?  It seems they get left out...

Comment: @abiessu: No, every bit gets inspected and incorporated. That's why a and b get divided by 2.

Comment: You're right, I mixed up my "negated input AND" logic and thought it would end prematurely.

Comment: Oh, no! You're right! That 'and' should be an 'or'. I have fixed it now.

Comment: In its present form this fails if $2|b$ and $a=0$ or $a=b$ (or vice versa).

Comment: @ozo: Does your comment refer to the version before my edit (with 'and'), or after it (with 'or')? I think it works now.

Comment: With 'or'. If I try it with, say, $a=b=1$ and $a=b=2$, then I get the same answer. Please check yourself in case I've made an implementation error.

Comment: How are you handling the signs in case $a$ or $b$ is negative?

Comment: @ozo: Yes, you are right. I have fixed that with f:=1 instead of f:=0; _perhaps_ it works now...

Comment: Yep, seems to work fine now.

Comment: Instead of interlacing the binary representations, couldn't we just concatenate them? It should give the same number of digits, but have simpler code (intuitively it is the same idea). You would still need to make sure to assign the same number of digits to $a$ as $b$ (so we don't accidentally get the same thing for two numbers by deleting leading $0$s).

Comment: Though perhaps I am wrong about simpler code - coding is not my forte.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I'm afraid the algorithm doesn't handle negative numbers at all as it stands. But you could fix this by (i) using the absolute values of a and b; (ii) shifting f left by 2 at the end; and (iii) saving the signs of a and b in the bottom two bits.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: That looks like a good suggestion to me. You still have some bit-counting to do, so you know how much to shift $a$ before you add $b$ (and you must shift the larger of the two, to avoid clashes). But some processors have a special instruction to count these bits, so if speed is important, your idea is preferable.

Comment: One final issue: $a\circ b\leq\max(a,b)^2$ is rarely true.

Comment: And indeed, I believe a simple pigeonhole argument should show that a quadratic bound is the best you can hope for.

Comment: This is a great idea, but has the unpleasant issue of overflow on a `uint32_t` scale for any value of `a` or `b` greater  than `UINT16_MAX`, and likewise for `uint64_t` where `a` or `b` are greater than `UINT32_MAX`.  My solution is to rotate bits in `f` rather than left shift (multiply by 2).  This introduces redundancy over a period of `UINT16_MAX` for 32-bit operations, and `UINT32_MAX` for 64-bit operations.

Answer (score 7):

**Note: This answer is substantially the same as the one given by JimmyK4542. I am leaving it here in case some minor difference in wording helps someone understand the derivation.**

If we can additionally assume that the integers are nonnegative, I believe that the following will satisfy the conditions given.

First note that commutativity can be guaranteed by sorting the elements, so without loss of generality we assume $a \geq b$.  Call the given pair which has been sorted $(a_0, b_0)$. We can identify the following sequence which uniquely transforms a sorted pair $(a,b)$:

\begin{aligned}
(0,0) &\rightarrow 0 \\
(1,0) &\rightarrow 1 \\
(1,1) &\rightarrow 2 \\
(2,0) &\rightarrow 3 \\
(2,1) &\rightarrow 4 \\
(2,2) &\rightarrow 5 \\
&\vdots 
\end{aligned}

From this it is clear that if we can compute the number of elements in this sequence which have $a < a_0$, and then add $b_0$, we have an answer that works. Let
\begin{equation}
N(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}{n} = (k)(k+1)/2
\end{equation}

Then we have a mapping
\begin{equation}
(a \, \& \, b) \rightarrow N(max(a,b))+min(a,b)
\end{equation}
which satisfies the two properties given.

As a benefit, this answer also scales only quadratically with the largest number in the pair.

Comment: It appears that the answer by JimmyK4542 was posted while I was typing this up.  What is the proper etiquette here (I'm new)? Should I delete my answer, being that it is basically the same?

Comment: The rule of thumb is: if you think that your explanation is clearer/more concise than someone else's then keep it. Otherwise, it's good etiquette to delete it.

Comment: @Hunter There is not really a consensus on this issue of etiquette. Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/about-posting-identical-answers-to-a-question) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/courtesy-etiquette-writing-an-almost-identical-answer-just-after-the-previous/12222#12222) for discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 7):

More programmerly than mathily, use a nondigit separator, like the convenient decimal point. In this case I concat a string together then cast it to a float.

```
c = parseFloat(max(a,b) + '.' + min(a,b))
```

***c*** will be unique and reversible for all interchangeable combinations of ***a*** and **b**.

so for example,

```
myhash(124,24) = 124.24
myhash(24,124) = 124.24

myhash(11231,26611) = 26611.11231
```

I think some index systems like the Dewey Decimal system and some part numbering schemes use this sort of bin-based technique.

But oops, then there is a problem if the second number ends with trailing zeros, so stringwise reverse it to preserve them:

```
c = parseFloat(max(a,b) + '.' + reverse(min(a,b)))
```

then

```
myhash(123,456) = 123.654
myhash(12300,4560) = 12300.0654
```

Comment: Whoops, this won't handle negative integers very well.

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $b$ are of a similar size then this limits them each to about 3 significant figures (32-bit IEEE float) or 8 significant figures (64-bit IEEE float).

Comment: You could encode the sign of `min(a,b)` in the first decimal digit (so for example `myhash(2,1) = 2.01`, `myhash(2,-1) = 2.11`).

Comment: @ozo That assumes they'll be stored in an IEEE floating point variable. That's a problem for the programming aspect, but not for the maths aspect.

Answer (score 4):

***Sort*** **a** and **b** ,then apply hash function.

c=hash(sort(a,b))

Here,

1. c is unique for the inputs and not reversible.
2. a and b are interchangeable (a & b = b & a).

Comment: All hash functions have collisions, multiple inputs with the same output. So this violates requirement 1. The probability of getting a collision for two randomly chosen inputs may be very low, and so not worth worrying about in practice, but it can theoretically happen.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes, and let

$$c=\min(p^aq^b,p^bq^a)$$

In fact this generalizes to a function for $n$ interchangeable variables $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, using distinct primes $p_1\ldots,p_n$:

$$c=\min_{\pi}\{\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{a_{\pi(i)}}\}$$

where the min is taken over all permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

(Note, the integers $a$ and $b$ need not be positive. The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic still guarantees that different multisets correspond to different values of $c$.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a rather simple way to do this using string operations:

1. Let x = min(a,b) and y=max(a,b)
2. Treating x and y as strings and + as the concatenation operator, let z = x + "|" + y
3. Use your favorite string to binary/hex/decimal function to turn z into a number.

Let's look at an example. f(25,-36).

x = -36 and y = 25.

z = "-36|25".

Using a standard ASCII to Decimal converter, we get the number 4551541245053.

Comment: I am trying to create combinations of a set of numbers in excel and thus realized that I need a function like the one mentioned in the main question of this thread. While I already tried 2^a + 2^b i realized it does not work for large a and b due to excel issues... but i  Found some really great mathematical answers on this page and learnt a lot.. William Forcier from an excel point of view your answer is awesome. I made only 1 change...instead of converting the concatted text to  a number I used a countifs and running countifs to weed out duplicates... Thank you very much for the base idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $\max(|a|,|b|)$ and $a+b$, we can recover the unordered pair $(a,b)$ as
$$
\textstyle\left(\min(a+b,0)+\max(|a|,|b|),\max(a+b,0)-\max(|a|,|b|)\right)\tag{1}
$$
There are $4n+1$ unordered pairs of integers so that $\max(|a|,|b|)=n$; their sums being
$$
\{-2n,-2n+1,\dots,0,\dots2n-1,2n\}\tag{2}
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(4k+1)=2n^2+3n\tag{3}
$$
we will set
$$
f(a,b)=2\max(|a|,|b|)^2+\max(|a|,|b|)+a+b\tag{4}
$$
Then the greatest $f(a,b)$ can be for $\max(|a|,|b|)=n$ is
$$
2n^2+n+2n=2n^2+3n\tag{5}
$$
and the least it can be for $\max(|a|,|b|)=n+1$ is
$$
2(n+1)^2+(n+1)-2(n+1)=2n^2+3n+1\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, the $f$ given in $(4)$ maps unordered pairs of integers to non-negative integers injectively (and incidentally, surjectively).

Comment: Beautiful. Looks like the best solution so far to me, since the OP apparently wants to use it as a perfect hashing function or something like that. -- There are parenthesis missing around $4k+1$ in (3).

Comment: @HansAdler: thanks. I can see your point about the parentheses, so I have added them. However, I usually write $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n4k$ when I intend the other association, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ are all the primes, then:

$f(a,b) = P(a)  P(b)$

```
f(0,0)=4
f(1,0)=6
f(1,1)=9
f(2,0)=10
f(2,1)=15
f(2,2)=25
f(3,0)=14
f(3,1)=21
f(3,2)=35
f(3,3)=49
```

$a$ & $b$ are interchangeable.
It is reversible, but very hard for large numbers of c.
I think this is also how asymmetric cryptography works in its most simple form with large numbers of '$a$' & '$b$'.

**Example:**

- 'P(a)' being the public-key on the server side
- 'P(b)' being the private-key on the client side
- 'c' being the token to be transmitted.

  1. client request access to server
  2. server transmits token to client and requests for a factor of it.
  3. client divides token with the locally stored private-key and send the result to the server
  4. Server compares stored public-key with given result, if same then grants access

Comment: And it works also if you have more then 2 input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since your answer need to be a integer the following simple steps should work:

1. Sort the numbers a and b with the smallest first if a = b just put a first.
2. Now put the first number in front of the dot and the second number behind the decimal, then append one to the end (so that if the second number ended in 0 it will now end in 01 to keep it unique)
3. now you have a unique easily reversible number.

This method will also be reasonably memory efficient, and also ensure uniqueness (and you can easily find a given b and b given a).

Comment: I see two difficulties with this approach: 1) The result for numbers with trailing zeroes won't be unique (`1.50 = 1.500`) - this can be resolved by reversing the number behind the decimal point. 2) the question states "integers", how can this function be improved to handle negative integers while still being injective?

Comment: @waldrumpus, as TonyK observed when I asked much the same question of his answer, you could handle signs by encoding $a\le b$ as $ax.yr$, where $r$ is $b$ written in reverse (as you suggested) and $x,y\in\{0,1\}$ to indicate the signs of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: added a simple trick just append 1 to the end and it will always be unique

Comment: @BarryCipra Very nice! Since this answer was the first thing to pop into my mind, I'm glad to see it improved and perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use complex numbers $u+vI$ with integer coefficients $u, v$. Let $c=a*b=(a+b)+abI$. It is easy to see that if we know $u=a+b$ and $v=ab$ then we know $a, b$. To see this consider the polynomial $x^2-ux+v$ then this has roots $a,b$.

If you want the answer to be real then you could use $(a+b)+(ab)\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another (and quite standard) solution is using the [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) $\pi:
\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$. It is a bijection. So now let's only find a bijection between unordered pairs ${\mathbb N}\choose{2}$ and ordered pairs $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$. One such is
$$\sigma:\{a,b\}\mapsto(\min\{a,b\},\max\{a,b\}-\min\{a,b\})$$
with the inverse
$$\sigma^{-1}:(x,y)\mapsto \{x,x+y\}.$$

Therefore $\pi\circ\sigma$ satisfies your requirements, moreover, it is a bijection between unordered pairs of natural numbers and natural numbers, so it's efficient.

If you need integers instead of natural numbers, use your favourite bijection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$, there's plenty of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since some seem to be talking about programming and this is too long for a comment, I'll post this answer even though *it's not really appropriate for a mathematics question*. Given two 16 bit signed ints `a` and `b`, you can sort them and or them together. Meaning:

```
int uniqueCombo(int a, int b) { //assuming -2^15<=a,b<=2^15-1
    if(a<b)
        return (a&0xFFFF)|(b<<16);
    else
        return (b&0xFFFF)|(a<<16);
}
```

This, by the magic of signed and unsigned integers, unless I'm mistaken, will handle positives and negatives perfectly fine and is easy to invert (to get a as a 32 bit signed int, take out the first sixteen bits. If the biggest place digit is a one, pad the new 16 large place digits with ones. Else zeros.)